# selecting Range of a column dynamically in Excel

Tags: vba, excel

I want the name of the workbook to be filled in column A up to the last row where data exist in the worksheet , the code I am using to find the last row where data exist is

```
lastRow = ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Row - 1 + ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Rows.Count
```

and the code store name upto column A10 is

```
Sub testValue()

strAddress2 = "A3:A10"

wbName = ThisWorkbook.Name

Range(strAddress2).Value = Left(wbName, InStrRev(wbName, ".") - 1)

End Sub
```

I want to select the range dynamically with the value stored in variable "lastRow" but not sure how to do that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
strAddress2 = "A3:A" & lastRow
```